# Double with custom quantity zero's after dot

Tags: java, integer, double

I have two `Integer` values and I need create `Double` value from combining this two values in following way:

`A.CB`

where:

`A` — first integer value
`B` — second integer value
`C` — zero's to match total length

Basically, `CB` is always have to be 9 digits in total, that's mean when `B = 1` I need that `C` will be `8` zero's, if `B=100` I need `C` will be `6` zero's.
To get this results:
`15.000000001`
and
`17.000000100`

What is the best way to approach this logic in code? I mean I can write custom method to create this logic, but is Java already have something for this case to just use it, without creating custom methods? Better if it's possible without using string format functions (to not convert Integer values to String).

Comment: If you don't want to convert to String, you'll have a problem whenever B ends in one or more zeroes. You can't set the precision of a Double to a specified number of decimal digits, because floating-point values don't have decimal digits (they have binary digits). So if you want to round/truncate to a specific number of digits, you'll have to convert into something with a decmial radix, via either `BigDecimal` or `DecimalFormat`. (Or to a String.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    int A = 123, B = 450;
    System.out.println(String.format("%.09f", A + 1e-9 * B));
```

Will print

```
123.000000450
```

---

P.S. `String.format` is required because of your trailing-zeros-after-the-comma requirement. Those zeros don't actually exist, so you need some way to *pad* your output, and `String.format` is a convenient way to do that. If you just want a `double` value, you don't need `String.format`.

Comment: Except that OP says, "Better if it's possible without using string format functions"

Comment: `17.000000100` and `17.0000001` are identical floating-point values. It's only a "problem" if OP wants to *display* a specific amount of digits, which implies some form of conversion to `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Divide `b / 1000000000.0`:

```
int a = 12;
int b = 123;
double x = a + b / 1000000000.0;
System.out.println(x);
```

Will print:

```
12.000000123
```

Unless `b`'s length is longer than 9 digits, you will get what you want.

Comment: Getting `17.000000100` as result is not possible with your solution. It will return `17.0000001` for `a = 17` and `b = 100`.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp this is a formatting problem and as the OP wants: * if it's possible without using string format functions*

Comment: Yes, but without it is not possible I think.

Comment: Of course it's not possible. The problem can be solved up to the point of the calculation of the double value. The representation of the value will be done by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 12;
int b = 123;

// How many digits in b?
int blen = (int)Math.log10(b);

// Make a string of zeros
String padding = "00000000".substring(blen);

System.out.println(a + "." + padding + b);
```

This will fail apart if b is very large, as blen will be larger than the padding, and so substring will fail.  Also, negative b will mess things up.